# Circuit solving

Tags: circuit-analysis

Find the power of each source and provide your answers based on passive convention
[image: the problem]

[image: my work]

so the problem was that the powers didnt add up to zero at the end, so I got some of the current and voltage values wrong...

Also, I dont know which power values are suppose to be negatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The first problem I can see is when using Cramer's rule. The correct expression should be (using your equations):

$$i_1=\dfrac{\bigg|\matrix{0.006&1\\-15&-1000}\bigg|}{\bigg|\matrix{1&1\\2000&-1000}\bigg|}=-3\text{mA} $$

You can then find \$i_2=9\text{mA}\$.

2) Also you are forgetting to square the current to find the power in the resistors.

With that:

$$(2\text{k}\Omega)(-3\text{mA})^2+(1\text{k}\Omega)(9\text{mA})^2+(15\text{V})(-3\text{mA})+(-6\text{mA})(9\text{V}) =0$$

Notice that I had to place a minus sign for the last term \$-(6\text{mA})(9\text{V})\$ and that is because the current is "comes out" of the terminal labeled as + in your schematic, which means the current source is supplying power. The voltage is actually supplying power too but you have the reference direction for the current going into the + term, that is why we didn't have to place a minus sign in front of that term, but anyway the current came back with a negative sign so everything still holds.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you went wrong, but the thing can be solved fairly quickly using superposition.

First set the current source to 0 and just solve with the voltage source present.
\$15\ {\rm V}/3\ {\rm k\Omega}=5\ {\rm mA}\$. So we'll say \$i_{1a}=-5\ {\rm mA}\$ and \$i_{2a}=5\ {\rm mA}\$.

Now set the voltage source to 0, and just consider the current source. This can be solved by inspection because using the current divider rule, the 2 kohm resistor will get 1/3 of the current and the 1 kohm resistor wil get 2/3 of the current. So \$i_{1b} = 2\ {\rm mA}\$ and \$i_{2b} = 4\ {\rm mA}\$.

Combining the two solutions, \$i_1 = -3\ {\rm mA}\$ and \$i_2 = 9\ {\rm mA}\$.

From there you can easily calculate the current through the voltage source (\$i_1\$) and the voltage across the current source (\$1\ {\rm k\Omega}\times 7\ {\rm mA}\$), and then you can calculate the power in or out of each component.

Answer (score 3):

While superposition is, I believe, the best way to approach this problem (as The Photon shows), since there is just one unknown node voltage, [node voltage analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis) is almost as good.

If you find the node voltage \$V_A\$ at the junction of the current source and two resistors, you have all you need to find the powers.

The node voltage equation is:

$$\frac{15\,\mathrm{V} - V_A}{2\,\mathrm{k\Omega}} + 6\,\mathrm{mA} = \frac{V_A}{1\,\mathrm{k\Omega}}$$

Solving for \$V_A\$ is just algebra:

$$V_A = \left(\frac{15\,\mathrm{V}}{2\,\mathrm{k\Omega}} + 6\,\mathrm{mA}\right)/\left(\frac{1}{2\,\mathrm{k\Omega}} + \frac{1}{1\,\mathrm{k\Omega}} \right)= 9\,\mathrm{V}$$

Can you take it from here?